# how to create SQL trigger using IF condition as well doing inner joins

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have below sample format table structure:

**CUSTOMER** table

```
CUSTID INT,//PRIMARY KEY
CUSTDATA VARCHAR
```

**EMPLOYEE** table

```
EMPID INT,//PRIMARY KEY
EMPDATA VARCHAR
```

**ITEM** table

```
ITEMID INT,//PRIMARY KEY
CUSTID INT,//REFERENCE KEY
ITEMTYPE INT //1 FOR CUSTOMER AND 2 FOR EMPLOYEE
EMPID INT
```

**MERGEDATA** table

```
MERGEID INT,
CUSTDATA VARCHAR,
EMPDATA VARCHAR
ACTION VARCHAR
```

Above I have four tables (`CUSTOMER, EMPLOYEE, ITEM` and `MERGEDATA`), now I want to create SQL Server trigger on the `ITEM` table for `INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` events, so whenever activity is done on the `ITEM` table it populates my `MERGEDATA` table with the action done on `ITEM` table.

So if any new rows get inserted into the `ITEM` table a new entry goes into the `MERGEDATA` table depending on the `CUSTOMER` or `EMPLOYEE` entries, like if there is any entry from customer it will add one entry in the `ITEM` table as well as in `CUSTOMER` table as below

**CUSTOMER** table

```
123, TESTCUSTOMER
```

**ITEM** table

```
1, 123, 1, 0
```

And same goes for Employee table too, however in the `ITEM` table row will be like `1, 456, 0, 2`.

Now I want to write if condition in Trigger that if there is entry from CUSTOMER table

```
IF (ITEMTYPE == 1)
//Entry in MERGEDATA will as below
```

**MERGEDATA** table

```
1, 123, 0, ACTION (will depend on type of trigger event trigger if INSERT(ACTION = INS), for update (UPDATE = UPD) etc
```

So in short I am looking below things in trigger:

- How to write IF condition in trigger
- How to do inner joins from other table in trigger

Please suggest!!

Thanks

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: @Marc_s, thank....I am using MS SQL 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be:

create **three** separate triggers - one for each operation. This makes it easier to determine the `Action`, and it also gives you the flexibility to turn on/off each operation individually. Furthermore, the trigger code will be smaller, easier to understand, easier to maintain.

Given that design, your trigger will be dead simple:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_Item_Insert 
ON dbo.Item FOR INSERT
AS 
   -- first insert customer-related data - if any
   INSERT INTO dbo.MergeTable(CUSTDATA, EMPDATA, ACTION)
      SELECT CustData, EmptyData, 'INSERT'
      FROM Inserted
      WHERE ITEMTYPE = 1

   -- then insert employee-related data - if any
   INSERT INTO dbo.MergeTable(CUSTDATA, EMPDATA, ACTION)
      SELECT CustData, EmptyData, 'INSERT'
      FROM Inserted
      WHERE ITEMTYPE = 2
```

When you create three separate triggers, just replace the `'INSERT'` value for `Action` with `'Update'` and `'Delete'` in those other triggers.

What I have trouble with is:

- what columns from `Item` should be stored into what column in `MergeData` ?
- your columns in `Item` or mostly `INT` - your columns in `MergeData` are `Varchar` - what kind of "conversion" do you want to apply here?

For more details, [see the excellent SQL Server Books Online documentation (freely available!) on `CREATE TRIGGER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi Marc...thanks, I am ok to create three triggers and don't bother about conversion above just sample table, what about using if condition for on the basis of type of entry so if there is any entry from customer then it will first check if ITEMTYPE = 1 then entry for customer and if ITEMTYPE = 2 entry for employee as well as how to get the EMPDATA and CUSTDATA from Employee and Customer table as trigger is on ITEM table

Comment: @ManojSingh: sure - you can easily insert first the new rows for `ItemType = 1` and then those for `ItemType = 2` - see my update